# How do I record audio with C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio-recording

I have an application to which I want to add the ability to import small audio snippets directly from a microphone device of some sort.

I already allow importing of pictures and this works okay with disk files and cameras since cameras magically become disk devices when you attach them so a file import method works for both.

Audio however is slightly different. I've already allowed for importing audio files off the disk but I want to add the capability to directly record from a microphone to a disk file or in-memory buffer.

Does C#/WPF provide an easy way to do this? What's a good way to add this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [voice record (winmm.dll) using C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838190/voice-record-winmm-dll-using-c-net)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161(VS.85).aspx) function:

```
public class Program
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("recording, press Enter to stop and save ...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        mciSendString("save recsound c:\\work\\result.wav", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library (there's a [sample](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/DirectShowSamples-2010-February.zip/download) called `PlayCap`).

You might also find this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cac.aspx) useful.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838190/voice-record-winmm-dll-using-c-net  Attribution required here.

Comment: Works great, thank you. I had been looking for this for far too long.

Comment: Just a note: these days you can use the NAudio NuGet package to get this kind of stuff done much easier.

Comment: how to record both audio and video into a single file, now i am able to record video and audio in separate file. please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the this library:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx
Mainly due to the simple api. But I don't like this code too much. For example it fixes it's buffers in memory for a long time instead of allocating unmanaged buffers.