# Recording audio from Microphone in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, audio-recording

I am working on a WPF application that includes record audio data, to be embedded in documents.

my question is how I can record audio and show volume waves on display!

### EDIT

I don't want Third Party libraries, there should be some solutions using direct-x or Windows API, Isn't there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no Windows API function to interpret waveform data so you can display it.

There are built-in methods for recording, for example any simple search will help: [How do I record audio with C#/WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694274/how-do-i-record-audio-with-c-wpf)

A wave file may be in an easily-interpreted format, i.e. they are usually uncompressed, 16-bit data, 2 bytes per sample, 1 sample for each channel (L,R), some header information and 44100 samples per second.  Unless you use a library, you'll have to do your own (simple) data processing to convert that to a waveform display.