# how to record audio and play it c#

Tags: c#, audio, record

I need this window to record an audio from microphone:
xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Mesius_Leitner_Professional.Record"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Record" Height="308" Width="378">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="start" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,132,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="stop'n save" IsEnabled="False" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,132,157,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="play" Height="23" IsEnabled="false" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,132,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Mesius_Leitner_Professional
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Record.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Record : Window
    {
        public Record()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

is there any standard lib or some additional classes I can use to record audio using just a simple command ?

Comment: That has already been asked.
Check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694274/how-do-i-record-audio-with-c-wpf][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694274/how-do-i-record-audio-with-c-wpf

Answer (score 0):

you can use winmm.dll

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);


mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

string Resualt = @"...\Desktop\Test\test.wav";

        mciSendString("save recsound " + Resualt, "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
```

I hope it can help you