# How to make a Audio record Feature like noteability

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording

Hello I'm currently working on a note taking application project and I need to implement a feature like the audio record in notability where the application records the sound and when you play the record it shows what you have written at that time. Has anyone an idea on how to develop something like that or has a tutorial?
The programming language I use is C#

Answer (score 1):

Look at [How do I record audio with C#/WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694274/how-do-i-record-audio-with-c-wpf)

You can save the file and name it to the char position in your text.