# How do I record audio in C# (Visual Studio 2017) on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, audio-recording

I have reviewed the previous question and answer on this topic ([voice record (winmm.dll) using C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838190/voice-record-winmm-dll-using-c-net)).  As the author says, it does not work on certain OS's.

When I use the recommended code on Windows 10 (VS 2017), it runs without error but creates no files.

As suggested, I used double quotes in the file location but it still does not work.

I have also confirmed that the microphone is working (I used dictation typing this question).

Any suggestions for recording audio in C# 2017 on Windows 10?

Comment: Please post what you have tried in code.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the issue more efficiently, maybe you can provide the code that you have tried.

The `mciSendString` works fine in my test, please refer to the following demo.

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendString", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int mciSendString(
    string lpstrCommand,
    string lpstrReturnString,
    int uReturnLength,
    int hwndCallback
);

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mciSendString("open new type WAVEAudio alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mciSendString("stop recsound", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("save recsound D://temp.wav", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("close recsound", "", 0, 0);
}
```